# Test iPhone Apps in Xcode 5 on a jailbroken iPhone 5S 7.0.6?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, xcode

How would I go about testing iPhone apps made in Xcode 5.0.2 on my jailbroken iPhone 5S 7.0.6? I read a tutorial on how to do it with Xcode 4.x, but it doesn't seem to apply anymore for Xcode 5.x.
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile

I really would appreciate an answer. I really don't want to buy a $99.00 developer account until my app is fully finished. Thanks again!

Comment: This article and the comment it jumps to when you click on the link should help: http://mhassan.me/2013/02/15/using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/#comment-124

Comment: If that answered your question either you or I could summarize that article here as an answer, so other people can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I'm actually stuck. When I get to the part that asks me too change my "Build Settings" "Code Signing Identity" too the one I created in Keychain Access, it doesn't show up? http://i.imgur.com/J5jxM2A.png

Comment: You should be able to select "Other..." and navigate to the certificate you just created (whether it be in a keychain or in a directory somewhere).

Comment: You also need to make sure that you specified the correct path for Xcode when setting up Xcode to allow the use of self-signed certificates. If this doesn't all work, you could always just install AppSync on your device and set Xcode to "Don't Code Sign."

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I have AppSync installed. When I set the "Code Signing Identity" to "Don't Code Sign" and try running it on my iPhone, I get a message that says "Build Failed."